# How to reference npm package to it's source code in IDE (WebStorm)?

Tags: angular, npm

`npm` packages in my Angular project contain only interfaces without `HTML` markup and source code, this makes development harder. I would prefer to be able to debug the original source code.

For example: HTML Tag: `ngb-carousel` leads in `WebStorm` to `node-modules -> @ng-bootstrap -> ng-bootstrap -> carusel -> carusel.d.ts -> NgbCarousel`. This is just an interface without markup. Full implementation can be found here: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.ts

I have two questions:

1. Where `npm` package contains the real implementation (I can see in WebStorm only interfaces)?
2. Is it possible to configure WebStorm/Node, so that my IDE leads to source code for `npm` packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This npm package doesn't have the actual source code. The library is built using Angular CLI - so the files published on NPM are some JS bundles. Even the original html markup of angular libraries is not preserved, as it's typically compiled ahead of time with Ivy into some convoluted JS code.

That's why the package also ships a `.d.ts` file - in order for your typescript app to be able to know types related to the package in the absence of the library's source typescript code.

Some libraries include the actual source code though. E.g. RxJS. WebStorm recognizes that and opens the source files for you.